# IDE with error messages on line? (like XCODE, for PC)

Tags: xcode, highlighting

Basically, I'm looking for an IDE for PC that's like XCODE. What I'm really looking for is the on line error highlighting, as seen here

[image: Error highlighting on line]

So far I haven't been able to find anything with this.

Comment: Xcode runs on a personal computer, so unless you are using "PC" to mean something other than that, I don't understand the question.  (eg, contrary to certain marketing beliefs, the phrase "PC" is not copyrighted by Microsoft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools) does a similar thing

(and yes, i find the 'pc' moniker for windows machines very disgusting)